# How to adjust size of letter background?

Tags: html, css

I have a word with a background colour. This is fine except that I want the background color a certain size in relation to the word. Simply putting `background-color: blue,`gives the word a background color and `display: inline-block` makes the color fit the word exactly. So far so good. The problem is as soon as I increase the font size, the background colour shape warps and either goes into a square covering half the word or goes into a line covering the width but not the height.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .about5 {
    color: red;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 90px;
    left: 320px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    bottom: 100px;
    z-index: 3 !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="about5">About</div>
```

This gives a background colour of blue which covers half the word but not the other half.

So how do I get it to cover the whole word and fit exactly, even to perhaps add a bit of padding?

Can I just apply width and height or is there another way?

Thanks.

The page is [here](https://4309.co.uk/about-us) and it differs according to desktop mobile.

Comment: Just tried your code with codepen and background covered whole word. But I did not fully see it and needed to add some div tags before your code,

I assume, the problem is not with background, but rather with tag location and other tags around. For example your word may overflow another tag while background does not overflow.

Comment: Thanks. Please see edited question and site.

Answer (score 1):

I inspected the element on your site and saw that your `about5` class has the attributes of `width` and `height` both set to 100px. Either you specified those dimensions or they were inherited from a parent element. Get rid of your `height` element only, then change `width` to `auto` and add `padding: 3%`. That's what ended up working for me in the Inspector for your site, although the code works just fine for me in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z0keyftb/

Comment: Thanks but how would that effect the size of my background?

Comment: Thanks. So if I width and height unset then it should work?

Comment: Which leads to me to a follow up question. Would adjusting width and height also adjust font size? If so, how do I target juts size of background color? Thanks

Comment: So I just unset width and height and, whilst it works in mobile, desktop still has a line through it and not covering whole word. Here https://4309.co.uk/about-us/

Comment: @Newstack I take that back. Get rid of your `height` element only, then change `width` to `auto` and add `padding: 3%`. Turns out getting rid of the two didn't work in the Inspector somehow, when it did work in my JSFiddle.

Comment: @Newstack Are you sure? Because it worked for me in Desktop.